# How to return true or false individually in code using .map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I get the data in the form of an array, and I use the .map() method to manage one state. I want to create an array that changes values ​​individually, but it keeps moving as one. Help me.

```
    function Follow() {
  const [isFollow, setIsFollow] = useState([]);

  const handleChangeButton = idx => {
    const newIsFollow = [...isFollow];
    newIsFollow[idx] = !newIsFollow[idx];
    setIsFollow(newIsFollow);
  };

  return (
    <FollowWrapper>
      <Title>
        <h5>follw</h5>
      </Title>
      <ul ref={ref}>
        {users.map((info, idx) => {
          return (
            <li key={idx}>
              <UserContainer>
                <UserInfo onClick={() => moveDetailPage(info.product_seq)}>
                  <UserImage
                  />

                  <TextWrapper>
                    <p>
                      <strong>{info.homepage_name}</strong>
                      <br />
                      {info.wholesale_client_id}
                    </p>
                  </TextWrapper>
                </UserInfo>
                <ButtonWrapper>
                  <FollowButton
                    isFollow={isFollow[users.length - 1]}
                    value={users.length - 1}
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleChangeButton(users.length - 1);
                    }}
                  >
                    follw
                  </FollowButton>
                </ButtonWrapper>
              </UserContainer>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <NavHeightBox />
    </FollowWrapper>
  );
}
```

How can I get the data and manage the state values ​​individually?
I tried to designate the state value individually, but it doesn't seem like a good way because I don't know how many data will come in.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is and what you are trying to resolve? What are you trying to manage individually?

Comment: I want to change the style individually when FollowButton is pressed, but I can't change the state value individually using .map. I don't know how to approach to solve this. please Help me

Comment: I have copied the array using handleChangeButton, but the state values ​​don't change individually.

Comment: The `isFollow` state? Is the problem in the `handleChangeButton` handler where you are trying to update/toggle a value?

Comment: Yes, that's right! Multiple buttons are created via .map method, I want to change state individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to be passing the correct "index" value to your `FollowButton` props or the `handleChangeButton`. You are effectively passing the last index (`users.length - 1`) to all of them. Use the mapped `idx` value.

```
const handleChangeButton = idx => {
  const newIsFollow = [...isFollow];
  newIsFollow[idx] = !newIsFollow[idx]; // <-- passed index
  setIsFollow(newIsFollow);
};

...

{users.map((info, idx) => {            // <-- current index
  return (
    <li key={idx}>
      <UserContainer>
        ...
        <ButtonWrapper>
          <FollowButton
            isFollow={isFollow[idx]}   // <-- current index
            value={idx}                // <-- current index
            onClick={() => {
              handleChangeButton(idx); // <-- current index
            }}
          >
            follow
          </FollowButton>
        </ButtonWrapper>
      </UserContainer>
    </li>
  );
})}
```

### Update

Since the `isFollow` array is initially empty, you can update any index you please and it will lead to `undefined` "holes" in the array until you "fill them in" by toggling the value there. `undefined` is a falsey value, so the negation is a truthy value. If you desire you can initialize the `isFollow` state to match the `users` array.

```
const [isFollow, setIsFollow] = useState(Array(users.length).fill('N'));
```

...

```
const handleChangeButton = idx => {
  const newIsFollow = [...isFollow];
  newIsFollow[idx] = newIsFollow[idx] === "Y' ? 'N' : 'Y';
  setIsFollow(newIsFollow);
};
```

IMO it would be simpler and more trivial to just keep `isFollow` a boolean type for easy toggling and derive in the UI what the "Y"/"N" value should be from the boolean state values.

Comment: wow fixed right away. thank you so much you saved me!!!! Thank you very much, I will study hard!!!! :)

Comment: Is there a way to return the state value as "Y" or "N" rather than random when the button is clicked?

Comment: @eenooyos Can you clarify that question? What is random? You can do something like `isFollow[idx] ? "Y" : "N"`. Where are you wanting/trying to do a "Y"/"N"?

Comment: The status value of isFollow is displayed in the console like this.
I want to manage it in "Y"/"N" rather than random format, is there a way?

Comment: [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, false, empty × 2, true]

Comment: @eenooyos Ah, well the `isFollow` array is initially empty, but you can specify and update any index you like. This leads to the `undefined` "holes" you see there. I'll update answer with a way to populate the `isFollow` state to match the `users` array.